# ICollection<> inside ICollection<> in Razor - can't retrieve the model names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable, icollection

I'm wondering how to resolve the problem. I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC app

I have a **`models`**

```
public class SearcherString
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Path> Path { get; set; 
    public SearcherString()
    {
        Path = new List<Path>();
    }
}

public class Path
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm passing it in my **`Controller`** (I'm writing my model into my database and then I'm retrieving it)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.SearchersString.ToList()
}
```

And I have a **`View`** with:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.SearcherString>
```

> The problem is in my View, I can't display the names from **Path model**
>   (**CategoryID**, **CategoryName**)

I tried to do:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            foreach (var path in item.Path)
            {
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName(path.CategoryID.ToString())
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName(path.CategoryName)
                </th>
            }
        }
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            @foreach (var path in item.Path)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => path.CategoryID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => path.CategoryName)
                </td>
            }
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

But I have only:
[image]

Could someone help me with this problem?

> Edit:

Is there a way to change the `Html.DisplayName` to `Html.DisplayNameFor` here?

```
@Html.DisplayName(path.CategoryID.ToString())
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Path` actually contains some elements

Comment: I added breakpoint on line **@foreach (var item in Model)** and it won't enter inside this **foreach**

Comment: Because your `Path` is an empty collection

Comment: So, what I should do?

Comment: Look at Kirill Bestemyanov's answer

Comment: Which means either your database does not have any items or you have not set up your navigation properties correctly

Comment: Yes yes, I had a mistake. Now it's working fine :)

Comment: I made an edit, could you look at it?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Path.CategoryName)` should work if I understand you correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include navigation property to your query:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.SearchersString.Include(c=>c.Path).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

Your Model is incorrect.

```
public SearcherString()
{
    Path = new List<Path>();
}
```

This is not a property. This is treated as a Method, a special one. And it is a constructor. That Creates a Path object That is EMPTY.

If you want to have a one to many relationship. You would have to use the property for this and add a property of ID.

```
public int PathID {get; set;}
public virtual Path Path{get; set;}
```

Now you have a lazy loading property that will automatically save the ID property of the Path class into your SearchString model property PathID.

to get the PathID, you will specifically need to call the include function if you're using EntityFramework, which most likely the case.

```
public ActionResult Index(){


  return View(db.SearchersString.Include(c=>c.Path).ToList();
}
```